# Can a spell-absorbing item absorb a counter spell cast as a reaction to a spell you cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

In D&D 5e, there are a few items that can absorb spells cast by another wizard. I know of at least two: the Staff of the Archmagi and the Rod of Absorption.

If I'm about to cast a spell and an enemy wizard casts counterspell to negate my spell, can I use my spell-absorbing item to negate their counterspell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes.

The text of those items says that they can only absorb spells that target you and only you: (DMG 195)

> While holding this rod, you can use your reaction to absorb a spell that is targeting only you and not with an area of effect.

The text of counterspell states that its target is a single creature that is casting a spell:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of Casting a Spell.

Therefore, it fulfills those criteria and can be absorbed.

Comment: There are certain schools of thought which argue that Counterspell has NO target, in which case this wouldn't work. But I agree with you.

Comment: Looks good, I thought that would be the case. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If i(z) am about to cast a spell (desintagrate), and there is 2 enemy wizards(X and Y),the X wizard cast a counterspells to negate my spell, I absorb that spells with my rod of absorbtion, but the second wizard (Y) can still counterspells Desintegrate??..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer reads more as a new question. If you have a new question, and cannot find that it has been asked before, instead ask a new question. Answers are for answering, not asking. Welcome to our site, and please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have a minute.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/83084)